# VS code showing warning when creating a new theme

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I am trying to create a new VS Code theme, but whenever I try to run the debugger vs code shows a warning "You don't have an extension for debugging 'JSON with comments'. Should we find a 'JSON with comments' extension in the marketplace?'

[image: screenshot]

My launch.json file:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Extension",
      "type": "extensionHost",
      "request": "launch",
      "args": ["--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}"]
    }
  ]
}
```

My package.json file:

```
{
    "name": "theme",
    "displayName": "theme",
    "description": "theme",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "engines": {
        "vscode": "^1.58.0"
    },
    "categories": [
        "Themes"
    ],
    "contributes": {
        "themes": [
            {
                "label": "theme",
                "uiTheme": "vs-dark",
                "path": "./themes/theme-color-theme.json"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I tried finding the JSON with comments debugger in the marketplace, but couldn't find it. Does anyone has any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: There is no such thing as a JSONC debugger. Its just an invalid configuration your using, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

##### When debugging a theme your **`"./.vscode/launch.json"`** should look like this:

---

```
  // "./.vscode/launch.json"

  {
      "configurations": [
          {
              "args": ["--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}"],
              "name": "Launch Extension",
              "request": "launch",
              "type": "pwa-extensionHost"
          }
      ]
  }
```

---

> ###### *"You only need four (4) settings total, which are displayed in the snippet above. Everything else is unnecessary junk when debugging a theme."*

---

#### You need to do one more thing:

###### At the very top of your `"./themes/theme-color-theme.json"` file add the following lines:

```
    // "./themes/theme-color-theme.json"

    {
        "name": "Your-themes-name",
        "type": "dark",
        "$schema": "vscode://schemas/color-theme",

        "colors": { 
            // theme highlighting...
         },
    }
```

#### EDIT:

---

I unintentionally added `"semanticHighlighting": true` to the snippet above. That's something that isn't related to this question so I removed it from the example. Semantic Highlight is important, though, and you should read about it before choosing true or false, if you haven't read about it already.